# What's the proper way to store this data in a MySQL schema?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, schema, database-schema

I have a `movie` in a MySQL database. A `movie` contains data attributes that will never change, such as the following:

- Barcode: 025192018626
- Format: DVD
- Runtime: 121 min.
- Discs: 1
- Title: 12 Monkeys
- Year: 1995

It's one single row in a table.

**But** I want to give my user's complete customization over this information in case something is incorrect according to them or if they just want to modify how the data is displayed in some way. I don't care why, I just want to give my users an option to do what they want.

Let's say User #1 wants to change the Title for them to be "12 Monkeys (Shelf 1)" and that's all they change.

And let's say User #2 wants to change DVD to Digital Copy instead.

And let's say User #3 wants to change the Title for them to be "Twelve Monkeys" because it's the alternative title.

etc.

My question is, how do I store *just* that one change to that one field for that username only, without modifying the original data? In a separate identical table with all fields the exact same data except that *one* field? Or can I just store that one single change (Title for example) somewhere and refer back to the `movie` data for the rest?

What's the proper way to design this, especially if I have 1000's of users making customized data modifications mostly on just one or two fields?

Comment: What about movies that have multiple titles? It's not just "Twelve Monkeys" vs. "12 Monkeys" but it could also be "L'armée des 12 singes" or any of the other names on [the IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114746/releaseinfo). This one-to-many relationship could be important for some, or maybe not. Also are you cross-linking things, like if they bought it as a DVD/Blu-Ray combo package?

Comment: Given that you know the columns that you are overriding, there is no need for using the EAV (attribute-value columns) designs that are proposed in some of the answers. Even if users can invent their own columns, before you use EAV you should demonstrate that it is superior to DML/DDL with straightforward tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of a single row for each movie, use an attribute-value table. Then add an additional field to this that specifies the user, which would be `0` for the original default. So the table looks like:

```
MovieID UserID  Attribute   Value
1       0       Title       12 Monkeys
1       0       Format      DVD
1       1       Title       Twelve Monkeys
```

Then a query to get the title would look like:

```
SELECT MovieID, IFNULL(my.Value, default.Value) AS title
FROM movies AS default
LEFT JOIN movies AS my ON default.MovieID = my.MovieID AND my.Attribute = 'Title' AND my.userID = @user
WHERE default.UserID = 0 AND default.Attribute = 'Title'
```

Some database designers also like to use an `AttributeID` rather than a string as the attribute name, and a separate table that maps attribute names to IDs.

Comment: Any upside to normalization with a `AttributeID`? Seems like an extra unneeded join?

Comment: I agree, that's why I don't do it. Some people are just really pedantic about normalization.

Comment: A possible advantage is internationalization. You could easily replace the attribute names with foreign values.

Comment: Barmier - Thank you, I didn't even think of that!

Comment: The obvious advantage is that you can change the `Attribute` caption (name) to something new whenever you want in future. Ie. you can change "Runtime" to "Run-time" by a very quick change in just 1 small table instead of updating thousands of rows. It keeps things clean. Otherwise this is an excellent solution I would not have thought of probably!

Comment: I suggest haveing  {MovieID, UserID,  Attribute} as primary key for the table to prevent duplicate data.

Comment: @EthanAllen & Barmar Re "upside to normalization": Introducing ids is not normalization. Normalization does not introduce new column names. Re "internationalization": You can replace attribute name values (or any other type of values) exactly the same as you can replace AttributeID values. There are reasons for introducing ids, mainly for naming things that don't already have names but otherwise when for performance (eg avoidance of cascades or integers being smaller than strings) they complicate schemas and queries.

Comment: @philipxy I don't know what the technical name for it is, but you presumably don't want a changeable column to be used as a foreign key in other tables. Internationalization is just one reason you might want to change the name column.

Comment: @philipxy I think some of us who are not database theorists tend to abuse the word "normalization" to refer to any "best practices" in database design.

Comment: If you need to have all the text both in English and in French, then that is "internalization" ("I15N").  I don't think that is what you are aiming at here.  (If it is, start over and label it as such; the solutions are significantly different.)

Comment: @RickJames I was just giving it as an example where someone might want to change the unique string in a record, so it's best to separate it from the primary key. Another example would be a user account system that allows users to change the username -- using the username as the primary key makes that difficult.

Comment: @Barmar - good point.  And a main reason for "normalization".

Answer (score 7):

I suggest there is no 'proper' way.  But you might like this...

- Your `Movie` table stays as is.  (I assume there is an `id`.)
- Another table, `UserMovie` with the same columns except:

  - All the columns except `id` are `NULL`
  - It has another column: `user NOT NULL`
  - `PRIMARY KEY(id, user)`

When a user modifies something, use `INSERT INTO UserMovie .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..` to change whatever field(s) he wants to set.  Note that IODKU will `INSERT` a new row if none exists, or `UPDATE` the existing row (because the user is modifying another column).  For example, to override just the "title" for id=$id,

```
INSERT INTO UserMovie
    (id, title)
    VALUES
    ($id, '$title')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    title = '$title';
```

When a user wants to see what he has,

```
SELECT  coalesce(u.title, m.title) AS title,
        coalesce(u.format, m.format) AS format,
        coalesce...
    FROM Movie AS m
    LEFT JOIN UserMovie AS u
            ON u.id = m.id
            AND u.user = $user
    WHERE m.id = $id;
```

The `COALESCE` quietly pics either `u.xxx` if `NOT NULL`, or `m.xxx`.

This design has the advantage of being very compact.  (`NULLs` take almost no space.)

If a user changes the "title" twice, only the last version is kept.

To "revert" the title:

```
UPDATE UserMovie SET title = NULL
    WHERE id = $id
      AND user = $user;
```

(Sure, this could leave a row of all `NULLs`, but the rest of the code still works.)

Comment: I like this idea, the problem I have is that I have to have two duplicate tables essentially. They have to have matching column names and types, so if I want to change something (say `desc - VARCHAR(255)` to `description - TEXT`), then I have to remember to do it in two places and there is no way to couple those two columns together to ensure that is done properly. But I am considering going this route as well, or something very similar.

Comment: Furthermore, you need to do them at `SELECT` time; the business logic does not let you combine them into one table.

Comment: `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` are compatible enough so that I don't see that as an issue.  That is, `COALESCE(u.varchar_col, m.text_col)` should work.  Or am I missing your concern?

Comment: Re "if I want to change something" This is specious. Tables share columns *all over the place*, *all the time*. This special case of one table sharing all those of another isn't any more of a "problem". (Use a transaction to change multiple tables simultaneously) PS Good bonus choice. PPS You can change what answer you accept, too.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought is, Why would you want to do this?

My second thought is to have a `customizations` table something like

```
+--------+---------+-------------+------------+
| userid | barcode | column_name | custom_val |
+--------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

then, when a user queries the system, look up their userid and the column_name in the `customizations` table to find the alternative display value.

This would allow a user to replace one value in one row. To replace one value in all rows where it exists would be a much more difficult proposition.

Comment: I agree with the approach. A downside of this is that all custom_val values will now have to be saved as strings, even though some of them are actually integers etc.

Comment: You could have `custom_val_str`, `custom_val_int`, etc. columns.

Comment: The "why" part has to do with implementing a user-based data correction technique I'm working on. Eventually I'll be developing a program that can see which users are changing which data (and the ratios of changes, etc), and implement some algorithms that correct or fill data automatically. This is especially important for foreign films, obscure movies, etc. that don't have full and/or correct data out there. It also goes beyond movies as well... but movies is just being used as the example here.

Comment: @Galz This is true, hence my first thought on the subject. ;)

Comment: @Barmar That could be done, but I should think it would get messy quite quickly.

Comment: @EthanAllen Would these custom values be displayed to everyone, or only to the user that made them?

Comment: @Darwin von Corax Just to the user who made them.

Comment: Then storing the display attributes as strings is less of an issue, unless you also want to allow users to search on custom values.

Comment: The one issue I can think of is a movie's Synopsis, which could be 1000's of characters long in `TEXT`. My guess would be to store `TEXT` data in a separate `customizations_long` table maybe?

Answer (score 2):

A good design is not perfect for all situations. However there is a perfect design for a situation.

Ask yourself again: 1) what the purpose of this design and, 2) how are you going to retrieve the data from the design.

According to your question, if a movie never changes its attributes, a flat one-row table is perfect:

```
table: movie
id | barcode      | format_id | runtime | disc | year_made | title
---+--------------+-----------+---------+------+-----------+-----------
1  | 025192018626 | 1         | 121     | 1    | 1995      | 12 Monkeys
```

And you might need a foreign table movie_format

```
table: movie_format
id | format
---+-------
1  | DVD
```

Above design is very speedy for search.

Now you want to save any changes, or alternative information, however not sure what they are. In this case, a meta table is more suitable. Meta table is usually perfect if you only need to display according to a primary key (a movie) and not used for a search:

```
table: movie_meta
id | movie_id | user_id | created             | meta      | info
---+----------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------
1  | 1        | 123     | 2016-01-28 11:22:33 | format_id | 2
2  | 1        | 456     | 2016-01-28 11:55:33 | disc      | 3
5  | 1        | 666     | 2016-07-14 12:58:55 | title     | 十二头傻猴子
```

You can make movie_meta.meta as enum so that you do not need to worry about a new lookup table