# Database Design Pattern for Maintaining a Draft Copy of the Record

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, revision

I have to implement a solution where our users can draft an entity first and publish it when they are done.

Once published the user can edit the published version, that should create a draft copy of the published version. The user can republish it after he is done with his edits.

- Entity Search should always show latest version.
- Need to maintain all previous versions for tracking purpose.
- Solution should work with Hibernate.
- Database that i'm using is MySQL.

Are there any proven database design patterns for this of kinda problem. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'll get more answers on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not just keep the data in your tables as normal, but flip a status of 'active' . All normal reporting could occur on the active rows (or at least from top down in a hierarchy). There is no reason to over-engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question : [What's the proper way to store this data in a MySQL schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212881/whats-the-proper-way-to-store-this-data-in-a-mysql-schema)

```
table: movie
id | year_made | rank | title
---+-----------+------+------------
1  | 1995      | 87   | Forest Gump

table: movie_log
id | movie_id | user_id | created             | attr  | info
---+----------+---------+---------------------+-------+--------
1  | 1        | 123     | 2016-07-14 12:20:34 | title | 阿甘
2  | 1        | 123     | 2016-07-14 12:21:34 | title | 阿甘正传
3  | 1        | 234     | 2016-07-14 12:22:34 | title | Forest Gump
```